# Как сделать fading эффект для картинок на сайте?

Tags: css

Как сделать fading эффект для картинок на сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Это пример на основе CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.fading a{
 color: #000;
 background: #ddd;
 padding: 10px;
 -webkit-transition-property: color, background;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 2s, 2s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
}

.fading a:hover {
 color: #eee;
 background: #a00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fading"><a href="#">Hover me</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Это пример на основе jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
div#hidden {
    background: #f00;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">Click me</a>

    <div id="hidden"></div>
<script>
      $(document.body).click(function () {
        $("div:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Вот.](http://vremenno.net/html-css/css3-review/)

Конечно есть варианты и получше. Но если только CSS то CSS3 Вам в помощь.Больше всех наверно вам понадобиться последние - Свойство background-clip.
А потом просто к всем IMG применить  что получиться.